# deploy to salesforce using python

Tags: python, soap, deployment, package, salesforce

I am new to python, I am trying to deploy a retrieved package into Salesforce using python, has anyone figured out any way to deploy metadata files(extracted zip) into Salesforce using python? i need to do it using python only, i need ideas and feasibility, what module should i use, what methods, and which parameters do i have to pass, also if any documentation available for deploy to Salesforce using python.
I was able to retrieve using soap API, now need to figure out how to deploy the same retrieved package using python.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [CumulusCI](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)? That is the open-source tool used by the NPSP project. You can import and utilize it from Python.

You will need [SFDX](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) in addition to CumulusCI, as it is basically a wrapper and added features around [SFDX](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli).